# Data duplicating on all items when saving with Ember-Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a page where a user edits an uploaded photo and applies a tag for individual photos on the model using Ember-Data. However, after saving on the controller, and transitioning to a page with all of the photos listed, the tag appears on all of the items and replaces any that existed before. If I reopen the page the tag has not saved at all.

I'm not quite sure what is causing this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//The photo model
App.Photo = DS.Model.extend({
  title: attr(),
  description: attr(),
  image: attr(),
  width: attr(),
  height: attr(),
  important_top: attr(),
  important_left: attr(),
  important_bottom: attr(),
  important_right: attr(),
  created: attr('date'),
  authors: hasMany('author'),
  app_data: {
    tags: []
  },
  imageURL: function() {
    return document.location.origin + '/media/' + this.get('image');
  }.property('image'),
});


// Photo edit route
App.PhotoseditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.store.find('photo');
    // Populate model with photos from the lowest upload ID to higest.
    return this.store.filter('photo', function(image){
      return image.get('id') >= App.Upload.uploadedImages[0]; // Get data from uploader
    });
  },
  activate: function() {
    $('#page-title').text('Edit Photos');
  },
});


// Photo Edit Controller
App.PhotoseditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    parsedTags: function() {
      // Get tags from the view's input field
      var tagData = this.get('app_data').tags;

      // Convert tags to an array
      return tagData.join(',');

    }.property('app_data'),

    // Watch parsedTags and apply array to model when converted
    parsedDataChanged: function() {
      Ember.run(this, function() {
        this.get('app_data').tags = this.get('parsedTags').split(',');
      });
    }.observes('parsedTags'),

  actions: {
    save: function() {
      var that = this;

      that.get('model').save().then(function(success) {
        that.transitionToRoute('photos');
      });
    }
  }
});

// Photo edit template
<h2>Edit Photo Meta Data</h2>
<button {{action 'save'}} style="float:right;">Save All</button>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each object in content itemController='photosedit'}}
    <tr>
      <td><img {{bind-attr src="imageURL"}} width="200" /></td>
      <td>{{input title valueBinding="title"}}</td>
      <td>{{input description valueBinding="description"}}</td>
      <td>{{input parsedTags valueBinding="parsedTags"}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{else}}
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">No photos yet.</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from the way you declare `app_data`. This variable will be shared across all instances of `App.Photo`, which explains why you see all photos getting the same tags.

You can solve this by initializing the attribute differently:

```
App.Photo = DS.Model.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.app_data = { tags: [] };
  }
});
```

instead of

```
App.Photo = DS.Model.extend({
  app_data = { tags: [] }
});
```

See this JsBin for an example highlighting the problem and the solution http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wawoq/3

Comment: When overriding init, you really should get in the habit of calling this._super(); before you do anything else in the function.

Comment: This worked perfect. Thank you for the help. One thing I've found is that the tags are not saving at all when I execute `that.get('model').save()`. Do you think this is happening because I'm defining tags and then trying to create that instance server side. Is there a better way to hand an instance like this?

Comment: Great! it's not saved because you haven't told Ember Data to serialize them (ie: declaring it with `DS.attr|belongsTo|hasMany`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that the store gets called with the correct data when you call save() and trace back from there.

Aside from this, parsedTags and parsedDataChanged seem to be referring to each other.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Your question is missing the entire context (all controllers, routes, models & templates) so it isn't possible to just give you a simple answer and point to what's going wrong. A jsbin is really quite handy in these cases. The answer was a good process for debugging given what you'd explained. If you'd like to share some more, it'll be more possible to help you :)

Comment: As mentioned by @JulianLeviston, your implementation of `parsedTags` and `parsedDataChanged` is buggy.

Comment: How should I implement parsedTags and parsedDataChanged differently?

Comment: I'd probably use a single computed property to implement your tags and connect that to the template. Check this out: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_setting-computed-properties